# validation for drop down select in mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In `MVC` form I have a `drop down list` which has 3 hard coded `options`.

```
                <select name="ComparisonType">
                    <option>select ..</option>
                    <option>Life</option>
                    <option>Income</option>
                </select>
```

On form submit values will be saved but there need to add validation for First option. If user submit form he should see message.

Please advice how to handle it. I'm not using Model here.

Comment: use jquery for this purpose.

Comment: On submit the form call the javascript function which will validate your dropdown.if user has selected the value then proceed to next step else prompt a message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your html as shown:

```
 <select name="ComparisonType">
   <option value="0">select ..</option>
   <option value="Life">Life</option>
   <option value="Income">Income</option>
 </select>
```

Jquery :

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
  if($('select[name=ComparisonType]').val() == "0")
  {
    alert("Please select any value from dropdown");
    e.preventDefault();  //or return false;
  }
});
```

**Edit :-**

[DEMO Link](http://jsfiddle.net/x2p53pa8/)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use **Javascript/Jquery** to achieve this functionality as you are not using a model here. So you can work around with this code which will validate your dropdown on submitting your form. Here goes :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submitButtonId').click(function (){
           var period = $("#dropdownId option:selected").text();
           if (period == "select") {
               //means first option is selected.
           }
           else {
              //some other option is selected.
           }
    });
});
```